# Comparing String to Integer gives strange results

Tags: php, casting, comparison

I'm really confused as to why this operation works.  Can someone explain it?

```
$test1 = "d85d1d81b25614a3504a3d5601a9cb2e";
$test2 = "3581169b064f71be1630b321d3ca318f";

if ($test1 == 0)
  echo "Test 1 is Equal!?";
if ($test2 == 0)
  echo "Test 2 is Equal!?";

// Returns: Test 1 is Equal!?
```

For clarification, I am trying to compare the string `"0"` to the `$test` variables.  I already know to fix the code I can just enclose (as I should have) the `0` in `""`s

I'm wondering if this is a PHP bug, a server bug, or somehow a valid operation.  According to https://www.php.net/types.comparisons this **should not** have worked.

**Edit:** Scratch that, apparently it does mention that Loose comparisons between string and 0 is true.  But I still don't know why.

**Edit 2:** I've revised my question, why does the `$test2` value of `"3581169b064f71be1630b321d3ca318f"` not work?

Comment: which $test value doesn't work?

Comment: If you run the code, it only outputs `Test 1 is Equal!?`

Comment: Edit 2 : because comparison statement automatically casts "3581169b064f71be1630b321d3ca318f" and as it starts with numbers its casted to int and gets the first part of string till a letter as value. and that comparison (3581169 == 0) to false

Comment: FWIW, *printing* the values of `$test1 + 0` and `$test2 + 0` would have given a clue as to what was happening.  Or alternatively, the values of `+$test1` and `+$test2` (using the identity operator).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[From the PHP manual](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion):

> **String conversion to numbers**
>
> When a string is evaluated in a
>   numeric context, the resulting value
>   and type are determined as follows.
>
> The string will be evaluated as a
>   float if it contains any of the
>   characters '.', 'e', or 'E'.
>   Otherwise, it will be evaluated as an
>   integer.
>
> The value is given by the initial
>   portion of the string. If the string
>   starts with valid numeric data, this
>   will be the value used. Otherwise, the
>   value will be 0 (zero). Valid numeric
>   data is an optional sign, followed by
>   one or more digits (optionally
>   containing a decimal point), followed
>   by an optional exponent. The exponent
>   is an 'e' or 'E' followed by one or
>   more digits.

Comment: Still don't think it should convert to a 0, or at least if it starts with a number not to convert to a decimal if there are erroneous characters in the string.

Comment: PHP has no "NaN" type like Javascript (another loose-typed language) so it pretty much has to convert to 0 as there would be no other way (converting to NULL wouldn't work cos NULL also converts to 0).  I think the answer is not to use a loose comparison (==), or to validate the string first.

Comment: **In addition to this answer**, when comparing 2 elements with `==` operator , it is converted to common type. it is mentioned here.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: The best way to do the test is to use the "empty" method: `empty($test1)`

Comment: @Pascal_dher - ugh, no. Reason: *say what you mean*. Here, the intent is to ask the question *"Is this value equal to 0"*.  An expression that looks similar to the intent is *obvious*, whereas an expression that relies on a quirk of the language, is *non-obvious*. IMHO. [If the only computer language that existed was PHP, then your suggestion would be reasonable. However, that still would not make it *the best* way; it would just make it an *equivalently good alternative*.]

Comment: Note that this has changed in PHP 8. It will now throw a `TypeError` if a non-numeric string is used in a numeric context. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.numeric-strings.php

Answer (score 12):

**Type conversion using the == operator**

The == operator is a loosely-typed comparison.  It will convert both to a common type and compare them.  The way strings are converted to integers is [explained here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).

Note that the [page you linked to](https://www.php.net/types.comparisons) doesn't contradict this.  Check the second table, where it says that comparing the integer `0` to a string `"php"` using `==` shall be true.

What happens is that the string is converted to integer, and non-numeric strings (strings that do not contain or begin with a number) convert to `0`.

**Numeric vs non-numeric strings**

A string that consists of a number, or begins with a number, is considered a *numeric string*.  If the string has other characters after that number, these are ignored.

If a string starts with a character that cannot be interpreted as part of a number, then it is a *non-numeric string* and will convert to `0`.  This doesn't mean that a numeric string has to start with a digit (0-9) - for example `"-1"` is a numeric string because the minus sign is part of a number in that case.

So for example, your string `"d85d1d81b25614a3504a3d5601a9cb2e"` does not start with a number, so it would convert to `0`.  But your second string `"3581169b064f71be1630b321d3ca318f"` would be converted to integer `3581169`.  So that's why your second test does not work the same way.

**What you should do**

You probably want:

```
if ($test1 === "0")
```

Notice the use of triple equals instead of a double equals.  This ensures that what you are comparing is a string that contains the digit zero only, and prevents any type conversion.

Answer (score 8):

After some investigation, it turns out aidan from the PHP manual mentioned that **any strings that do not start with a number** will be converted to 0 when casted as an integer.

This means that:

```
("php" == 0) === true
("1php" == 0) === false
```

Very annoying and not well documented.  It was at the bottom of the comments on the type comparison page.

Comment: Yeah, figured that was it. Poor documentation indeed.

Comment: I don't think it's poor documentation at all.  Implicit type conversion is a fundamental of PHP which is explained very well in the manual in the section on Types, particularly the Type Juggling section.  == is a loosely typed comparison; using === instead can help prevent confusing situations.

Comment: See also "String Conversion to Numbers" at http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Answer (score 2):

```
$test1 = "d85d1d81b25614a3504a3d5601a9cb2e";
```

this string starts with a "d", which is not valid number, the var will resolve to 0 and your test#1 will pass.

```
$test2 = "3581169b064f71be1630b321d3ca318f";
```

this string starts with 3581169 which is a valid number, so the var will resolve to that value which is not equal to 0. 
So your test#2 will not pass.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using some conversions and comparisons to test if a **numeric string** is a number:

```
$test1="19de6a91d2ca9d91721d82f1bd8102b6";
   echo (float)$test1==$test1; //TRUE
   echo is_float($test1); //FALSE

   //Converting the string to float and then converting it to string and compare will do the trick 
   echo (string)((float)$test1)==(string)$test1; //FALSE


$test2="5.66";
   echo (float)$test2==$test2; //TRUE

   //Testing the numeric string using `is_float` wont give the expected result
   echo is_float($test2); //FALSE

   echo (string)((float)$test2)==(string)$test2; //TRUE
```