# PHP test if ('a' == 0)

Tags: php, char, numbers, comparison

I know that `'0' == 0` is true in PHP, but *this*:

```
<?php
    if ('a' == 0)
        echo "YES";
?>
```

will print `YES` on the screen.
This bothers me. The question:

Why the string 'a' (or "a") is equal to the number 0?
I was thinking about automatic char->number conversion, but `'b' == 1` is `false`...

PHP Versions tested:

- 5.4.4-14+deb7u14
- 5.3.29

Comment: See also [Comparing String to Integer gives strange results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672040/comparing-string-to-integer-gives-strange-results)

Comment: To get the ASCII code of the letter use `ord('a')`