# var_dump(0 == 'all'); // WHY TRUE

Tags: php

I don't understand below output . found below expressions on php.net manual in boolean section.

```
<?php

    var_dump(0 == 'all');//   IS bool(true)
    var_dump((string)0 == 'all');  //IS bool(false)
    var_dump(0 === 'all'); // //IS bool(false)

?>
```

Comment: A gotcha of PHP type juggling http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: `If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.`

Comment: try `var_dump((integer)'all');` and `var_dump((integer)'32all 0');` and i think you will understand

Comment: That was already asked in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672040/comparing-string-to-integer-gives-strange-results

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing String to Integer gives strange results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672040/comparing-string-to-integer-gives-strange-results)

Answer (score 8):

If you compare an integer with a string, each string is converted to a number, so:

```
(0 == 'all') -> (0 == 0) -> true
```

The type conversion does not happen when the comparison is `===` or `!==` because this also includes the comparison of the *type*:

```
(0 === 'all') -> (integer == string) -> false
```

The second line of code you wrote force the integer value to be considered as a string, and so the numerical cast doesn't happen.

Comment: `(integer == string)` Think you forgot a `=`

Comment: @Rizier123 not really, because `integer == string` is written as pseudo-code and logically is always false. He wrote it like that so casuals can understand difference between `==` which compare values to `===` which compare values **and** types.

Comment: The code I wrote should be considered as _pseudo code_, and so, it doesn't matter how many `=` occurs between the `->` and the `<-` chars.