# PHP: Strange behaviour with variable assignment

Tags: php, variables

I'm declaring a var `$t` and assigning it a value of 0. I then reassign `$t` a new value of `test`. It then appears that `$t` is both `0` AND `test`. Here's the code:

```
$t = 0;
$t = "test";

if($t == 0 && $t == "test"){
    echo "unexpected";
}else{
    echo "expected";
}
```

The output is:

```
"unexpected"
```

Can someone please explain what is going on here? Is `$t` really two different values (`0` and `test`) at the same time or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but if you make the code just: $t = 'test'; if($t == 0) {echo 'yes';} it echos yes. So apparently the string evaluates to the same value as 0.

Comment: Visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672040/comparing-string-to-integer-gives-strange-results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This "strange" behaviour results in because of PHP's type juggling. Since you're using loose comparison `==` to compare to an integer `0` the string `test` is being converted to an integer, which results in conversion to `0`. See the [Loose comparison `==`](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) table. There in the row with the string `php` you'll see that it equals to the integer `0`, which applies to all strings.
You should be using strict (type) comparison operators, i.e. `===`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not appending or concatenating so it shouldn't be. Try the identical comparison operator instead.

```
if($t === 0 && $t === "test"){
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP MANUAL STATES:

> The value is given by the initial portion of the >string. If the string starts with valid numeric >data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the >value will be 0 (zero). Valid numeric data is an >optional sign, followed by one or more digits >(optionally containing a decimal point), >followed by an optional exponent. The >exponent is an 'e' or 'E' followed by one or >more digits.

http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

So `$t == 0` is true. You have to use strict comparison `===`

Answer (score 0):

Hey buddy use "===" operator for your comparison.

In php we can assign any value to a simple variable, it holds numeric, float, character, string, etc.

So always use "===" operator for unique or same value matching.