# PHP unexpected return value

Tags: php

I am using a class from somebody else and are getting an unexpected result. I already have an idea how to work around it, but I would like to understand why this happens.

```
class Pay {
  public function checkStatus {
    $check[0] = "000000 OK"
    return $check[0]
  }
}

$status = $cart->checkStatus ();
$payed = ( $status == "000000 OK" ? true : false);
```

The problem is that $status is somehow 1 when printing (could be also 'true' (have to check later at home)). Also payed is set to 'true' while I expect 'false' because of the wrong value of $status. 
Hope somebody can explain to me what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of your numeric or boolean value in `$status`. This causes your bit `$status == "000000 OK"` to evaluate your string to a numeric value (which is `1`), thus resulting in `true`.

Please see this questions accepted answer for further explaination:

[Comparing String to Integer gives strange results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672040/comparing-string-to-integer-gives-strange-results)

Comment: I still don't understand why $check[0] gets changed from a string to an int or boolean when it gets saved into $status

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$payed = ( $status === "000000 OK" ? true : false);
```

`===` operator checks if $status and your string are equal and from the same type (string). More information you can find here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

I tested it:

```
class Pay {
  public function checkStatus() {
    $check[0] = "000000 OK";
    return $check[0];
  }
}

$cart = new Pay();
$status = $cart->checkStatus();
echo $status; // returns "000000 OK"
$payed = ( $status == "000000 OK" ? true : false);
echo $payed; // returns 1
$payed = ( $status === "000000 OK" ? true : false);
echo $payed; // returns 1
```

If i echo `$status` it returns `000000 OK` as string. I don't know whats your problem.

Comment: That would then probably solve that $payed is not what I expect, but I still don't understand why $check[0] gets changed from a string to an int or boolean when it gets saved into $status

Comment: updated my answer.. i dont know whats your problem. `$status` variable returns the string `000000 OK` as expected.