# Very strange behaviour in PHP

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
$test = 0;
if ($test == "on"){
    echo "TRUE";
}
```

Result of this code will be:

```
TRUE
```

WHY??? My version of PHP: 5.4.10.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672040/comparing-string-to-integer-gives-strange-results

Comment: because `(int)"on"` equals to `0`

Comment: @Armen actually,`int` of *ANY* string is 0, that's why it will always be true if compared to 0. (try `intval("anystringyouwanthere")`)

Comment: @Jencen actually i'm not the question asker :), i know that i was answering to question

Comment: @Armen and I was just following up on your answer for the benefit of Weltkind ;)

Comment: @Jencen `intval('123foobar')`...

Comment: @Jencen 
`echo intval('456-Oh-Hi-This-is-not-0');` Is actually **456** :)

Comment: Brilliant guys, my bad generalizing *ALL* strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the switch statement. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is === or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.

```
$test = 0;
if ($test === "on"){
    echo "TRUE";
}
```

PHP will convert the string to number to compare. Using `===`, will compare the value as well as the type of data.

```
var_dump(0 == "a"); // 0 == 0 -> true
var_dump("1" == "01"); // 1 == 1 -> true
var_dump("10" == "1e1"); // 10 == 10 -> true
var_dump(100 == "1e2"); // 100 == 100 -> true
```

[Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: Yes. === works fine.  But 0!="on", I think so :)

Comment: That's because of the conversion. Check the updates.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are comparing `$test` with string value not binary value, if you want to compare with string value, try with `===` comparison, for 
`value + dataType`.

In your example, `var_dump(0=="on");` always return `bool(true)`.

But when you use `var_dump(0==="on");` it will give you `bool(false)`.

**[Example from PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):**

```
var_dump(0 == "a"); // 0 == 0 -> true
var_dump("1" == "01"); // 1 == 1 -> true
var_dump("10" == "1e1"); // 10 == 10 -> true
var_dump(100 == "1e2"); // 100 == 100 -> true
```

Answer (score 3):

If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the switch statement. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is === or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.

So use "===" for comparision.

Refer the link : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

This is because your are doing `==`
`0` is integer so in this `on` converted to int which is 0
So your if statement looks like `0==0`

For solution You have to use `===`

```
if ($test === "on")
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, loose comparison between integer and  non-numeric string (i.e string which cannot be interpreted as numeric, such as "php" or in your case "on") will cause string to be interpreted as integer with value of 0. Note that numeric "43", "1e3" or "123"  is a numeric string and will be correctly interpreted as numeric value.

I know this is weird.