# The simplest Q ever. $var != 0 in PHP

Tags: php

The example code is ok.

```
if ($xxx != false) {
    echo 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
} else {
    echo 'aaaaaaaaaaa';
}

// result: xxxxxxxxxxx


if ($xxx !== 0) {
    echo 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
} else {
    echo 'aaaaaaaaaaa';
}

// result: aaaaaaaaaaa
```

But this one confuses me

```
if ($xxx != 0) {
    echo 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
} else {
    echo 'aaaaaaaaaaa';
}
// result: aaaaaaaaaaa
```

$xxx is string, why this code returns me false?
I have read the document http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php but still don't understand about it.

Comment: What's the value of $xxx when the comparison occurs?  We can't help you without knowing that.  In the meantime [maybe you'll find your answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/672040/6096242).

Comment: $xxx is bool type ?

Answer (score 0):

if assigned value was this: `$xxx='0'` (string type numeric value), then the condition `if ($xxx != 0)` will return FALSE; That is, it is trying to compare with it's numeric values.

**CASE-1:**

```
$xxx = '0';
if ($xxx != 0) {
    echo 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
} else {
    echo 'aaaaaaaaaaa';
}
// result: aaaaaaaaaaa
```

**CASE-2:**

```
$xxx = '0';
if ($xxx !== 0) {
    echo 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
} else {
    echo 'aaaaaaaaaaa';
}
// result: xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php for string

if your string is null then the behavior is the same that in your quetion

```
Loose comparisons with ==

NULL --> TRUE

Strict comparisons with ===

NULL --> FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Because != is not a clever one. It cant determine exactly whether this value is string type or boolean type.

You should use !== instead if you want exact comparison

Answer (score 0):

```
$var1 = false;  // yes
if ($var1 == 0) echo 'yes'; else echo 'no';

$var2 = 0;  // yes  integer convert to boolean
if ($var2 == false) echo 'yes'; else echo 'no';

$var3 = '0';  // yes  string 2 integer 2 boolean
if ($var3 == false) echo 'yes'; else echo 'no';

$var4 = 0;  // no  integer not 2 boolean
if ($var4 === false) echo 'yes'; else echo 'no';

$var5 = '0';  // no  string not 2 integer and not 2 boolean
if ($var5 === false) echo 'yes'; else echo 'no';
```