# php inline if statement not working

Tags: php

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but the inline if statement always returns true, even if it is not supposed to.

I have the following statement

`<?php echo ($total == 'Scratched' || ($total > 0 && $total < 65)) ? 'ffefef' : 'f7f7f7'; ?>`

Just above this statement, I echo `$total` and that echoes out `0`

At the top of the page I define
`<?php $total = 0; ?>`, so `$total` is defined as an integer.

The above if statement only returns false if `$total > 64` but not when total is 0

Thanks in advance

Comment: @MarkBaker, but there is no nested ternaries in the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working

```
<?php 
$total = 0;
echo ($total === 'Scratched' || ($total > 0 && $total < 65)) ? 'ffefef' : 'f7f7f7';
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

It's because `0 == 'Scratched'`

```
 // Strict comparison fixes it
 echo ($total === 'Scratched' || ($total > 0 && $total < 65)) ? 'ffefef' : 'f7f7f7';
```

Answer (score 3):

Base on your given situation. If I understand it quite well. Your state wont accept it as false if its `0`.

The above code should work. But try explicitly adding the not equal zero:

```
echo ($total === 'Scratched' || ($total > 0 && $total < 65 && $total != 0)) ? 'ffefef' : 'f7f7f7';
```

> Also added `===` to make sure the first statement of type *string*.

Answer (score 1):

Use `===` to compare `$total === 'Scratched'` and that will fixed

```
 <?php echo ($total === 'Scratched' || ($total > 0 && $total < 65)) ? 'ffefef' : 'f7f7f7'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try strict comparison:

```
<?php echo ($total === 'Scratched' || ($total > 0 && $total < 65)) ? 'ffefef' : 'f7f7f7'; ?>
```

Because of comparing a numeric variable over a string, the string is evaluated in a numeric context and represents 0.

You can take a look at the folowing post:
[Comparing String to Integer gives strange results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672040/comparing-string-to-integer-gives-strange-results)