# How to check if the DB already have the data or insert new data

Tags: php, mysqli

What I want is that php check if the client IP address is the same one which in the DB if it already exists, if not to insert new data.
well, it works if the client isn't already inserted in the database, but if he already exists php is skipping the update and trying to insert it again in the database............
I don't know whats wrong with it and couldn't figure out.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
$corruser = $_SESSION['user_name'];
$client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
require_once 'connections/dbc.php';
if (!$conn) {
  echo "Error connecting the database";
  exit();
} else{
  $GUI = "SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE user_name='$corruser'";
  $GUI_response = mysqli_query($conn, $GUI);
  if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($GUI_response)) {
    echo "Error while query the database";
    exit();
  } else{
  $customer_id = $row['customer_id'];
  $check = "SELECT * FROM `users-ipdb` WHERE customer_id='$customer_id' AND user_name='$user_name' ";
  $check_response = mysqli_query($conn,$check);
  $check_result = mysqli_fetch_array($check_response, MYSQLI_NUM);
  if ($check_result[0] > 1) {
    $update_ip = "UPDATE `users-ipdb` SET `client_ip`='$client_ip' WHERE customer_id='$customer_id' AND user_name='$corruser' ";
    $update_ip_result = mysqli_query($conn, $update_ip);
    if (!$update_ip_result) {
      echo "ERROR UPDATING DATA BASE";
      exit();
    }
  } else{
  $insert_new = "INSERT INTO `users-ipdb`(`customer_id`, `user_name`,`client_ip`) VALUES ('$customer_id','$corruser','$client_ip')";
  $insert_new_result= mysqli_query($conn, $insert_new);
  if (!$insert_new_result) {
    echo "Error inserting new data in the database";
    exit();
  }
}

}
}
?>
```

Comment: You are not actually checking if the IP exists anywhere in this code

Comment: Have you looked into `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` ?

Comment: Look into the concept of an "upsert". With MySQL, it's as easy as `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: You should parameterize your queries.

Comment: @WebCode.ie well I'm checking if the user is completely inserted in the database because there is no way in my DB structure to have the user without the IP so its automatic

Comment: Change your `$check` to this: `$check = "SELECT * FROM users-ipdb WHERE customer_id='$customer_id' AND user_name='$corruser' AND client_ip='$client_ip' ";` which users the correct username (undefined otherwise) and adds a where clause on the IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made an error with this code :

```
  $check = "SELECT * FROM `users-ipdb` WHERE customer_id='$customer_id' AND user_name='$user_name' ";
```

`$user_name` variable doesn't exist, you should replace it with `$corruser`

That's why the code never goes into the UPDATE

Comment: HAHAHAHA lool Thank you very much. :)

Comment: happy the have helped you !

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that your condition does work as expected. If `customer_id` is not a number the following line:

```
if ($check_result[0] > 1) {
```

can be possibly evaluated as `if(0 > 1)` let you read this:

[Comparing String to Integer gives strange results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672040/comparing-string-to-integer-gives-strange-results).

The other comments mention "UPSERTS" which are explained here https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/

The basic idea is that you can do

```
INSERT INTO `users-ipdb`(`customer_id`, `user_name`,`client_ip`) 
VALUES ('$customer_id','$corruser','$client_ip')" 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE client_ip='$client_ip';
```

and you get rid of the all the php logic. For this to work properly `customer_id` and `user_name` must be *both* part of the `PRIMARY KEY`.

If you need to query multiple tables, you can use joins - if you use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE you don't need them, but still a good thing to know - https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/join-syntax/

Last, but not least - it is a good habit to escape any value which may come from other sources. Maybe it is not your case, but some people tend to create usernames like `Joe';DROP TABLE mysql.user;SELECT '` and it will destroy your database, because your query will become

```
SELECT * FROM `users-ipdb` WHERE customer_id='$customer_id' AND user_name='Joe';DROP TABLE mysql.user;SELECT ''
```

So be careful.

Comment: Well, first of all, Thank you very much for you awesome explain, and thank you for warning me about the value escape, but the $customer_id is taken from other DB as well as the $user_name and in the signup code I've escaped them already :) the only one which may be a danger is the $client_ip.

But very much other ways for the explanation.