# foreach loop adding string to specific values

Tags: php

I am trying to add a string to a value in my foreach loop for 2 specific values. I **have** to use the function `in_array()` because it is a school exercise. For some reason, it's not working how I want it to work.

I have tried to use an `if` statement when the key matches the value, but it's adding the string to the first value of the index, instead of the specific value I want from the array.

Description: Print the array and add the string "new" to Beautiful People and Higher Love. Use the function `in_array()`. Other functions aren't allowed.

```
$thisWeek = array(
    'Dance Monkey',
    'Circles',
    'Beautiful People',
    'Blue Day',
    'Higher Love'
   );



 foreach ($thisWeek as $key => $value) {

if (in_array("Beautiful People", $thisWeek)  && $key== "Beautiful People") {
  echo "$key => $value  - new <br>";
  }
else {
  echo "$key => $value <br>";
  }
}
```

**Expected output should be:**

0 => Dance Monkey

1 => Circles

2 => Beautiful People - new

3 => Blue Day

4 => Higher Love

**I'm getting this:**

0 => Dance Monkey - new

1 => Circles

2 => Beautiful People

3 => Blue Day

4 => Higher Love

Also, I have to put the string "new" besides Higher Love. I am testing one value now. Why isn't it working and the code is adding the string to the first key-value instead of the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to other answers, going from

```
if (in_array("Beautiful People", $thisWeek)  && $key== "Beautiful People")
```

To

```
if (in_array("Beautiful People", $thisWeek)  && $value == "Beautiful People")
```

is redundant since you are looping `$thisWeek`.

If this statement `in_array("Beautiful People", $thisWeek)` is false, this one `$value == "Beautiful People"` will never be true.

Your condition can be simplified to :

```
if ($value == "Beautiful People")
```

However, your task is to find if the `$value` is either `"Beautiful People"` or `"Higher Love"`

You can either write it like this :

```
if ($value == "Beautiful People" || $value == "Higher Love")
```

Or :

```
// An array containing the values you are looking for
//                                     |
// Current value +   +-----------------+-----------------+
//               |   |                                   |
//               v   v                                   v
if (in_array($value, [ "Beautiful People", "Higher Love" ]))
```

Comment: Yeah, but maybe he should use *in_array()* before the loop?

Comment: Academic exercises can sometimes ask for the weirdest things.  I agree it's pointless in this context, but without greater scope of what they are doing it seems like a fudge.

Comment: Oh I think I got it.

Comment: _Pointing out_ that using in_array makes rather little sense here might be part of the expected result of the exercise, who knows :-)

Comment: @04FS yep, I just figured out that part

Comment: @therealise do you understand why ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working as you want because `$key` is your current index, and you are comparing it to a value. So you should change:

```
if (in_array("Beautiful People", $thisWeek)  && $key == "Beautiful People")
```

to:

```
if (in_array("Beautiful People", $thisWeek) && $value == "Beautiful People")
```

Answer (score 1):

In your test...

```
if (in_array("Beautiful People", $thisWeek)  && $key== "Beautiful People") {
```

`$key` is the index of the line and not the value, so change it to

```
if (in_array("Beautiful People", $thisWeek)  && $value == "Beautiful People") {
```

As to why it gives the strange results, have a read of [Comparing String to Integer gives strange results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672040/comparing-string-to-integer-gives-strange-results)

Answer (score 0):

You should change, `$key` with `$value`:

```php
$thisWeek = array(
    'Dance Monkey',
    'Circles',
    'Beautiful People',
    'Blue Day',
    'Higher Love'
);

foreach ($thisWeek as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array("Beautiful People", $thisWeek)  &&  ($value == "Beautiful People")) {
        echo "$key => $value  - new <br>";
    } else {
        echo "$key => $value <br>";
    }
}
```

the first condition is equivalent to the second, so you can reduce to:

```php
if (in_array("Beautiful People", $thisWeek))
```