# why does in_array return true when a value only begins with what is in an array

Tags: php

I've noticed a strange thing about **PHP**'s `in_array` function. For some reason, it will only check if the first character(s) of the needle match with any of the values of the haystack - as opposed to if the whole needle is in the haystack.

For example, in a situation where `$string` equals `1thisisatest`, the following script will return `In array`.

```
$allowed = [0, 1];
if(in_array($string, $allowed)){
    echo "In array";
} else {
    echo "Not in array";
}
```

Whereas if `$string` equals `2thisatest`, the script will return `Not in array`.

Now either this is a bug, or a very strange feature. Wouldn't you want it to check needles against the haystack **exactly** as they appear?

If this is, indeed, how the function is supposed to work, how does one go about getting the intended result without iterating over *every single element* in the array? Seems kind of pointless.

**EDIT**:

Some of you are saying to use strict mode. This is all fine and dandy, until you checking against `$_GET` data, which is **always** a string. So the following will return `false`:

```
$value = $_GET["value"]; // this returns "1"
in_array($value, [0, 1], true)
```

Comment: Use the `strict` parameter to check. From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php): "_If the third parameter strict is set to TRUE then the in_array() function will also check the types of the needle in the haystack._"

Comment: @kerbholz does that not just enforce type checking? :o

Comment: Probably due to [Comparing String to Integer gives strange results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672040/comparing-string-to-integer-gives-strange-results)

Comment: Make the array an array of strings rather than numbers.

Comment: @Barmar I like your style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `in_array` function uses the `==` operator. Thus `1 == "1thisisatest"` - so, `in_array` will return `true`.

To fix this you can enabled [**strict**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) mode:

```
// in the third parameter (to use === instead of ==)
in_array($search_value, $array_name, true)`
```

Answer (score 1):

`in_array` by default uses `==` which will follow the rules of [type juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

The solution is to use strict comparison:

```
in_array($value, [0, 1], true);
```

If you are concerned about `$_GET` variables you need to ensure you always validate and sanitize your input before using it otherwise you might end up with strange results:

```
$value = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'value', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
in_array($value, [0, 1], true);
```

It is always good to validate and sanitize your input to avoid things like e.g. someone calling your URL as `?value[]=1` which will mean `$_GET['value']` will be an array causing (most likely) errors in the best case and strange undocumented behaviour in the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

Make `$allowed` an array of strings and use strict mode.

```
$allowed = ["0", "1"];
if (in_array($_GET['value'], $allowed, true)) {
    echo "In array";
} else {
    echo "Not in array";
}
```

Comment: You forgot to enable strict mode hehe

Answer (score 1):

If you need to be more accurate you have to put the boolean `true` in your function like this:

```
$string = "1thisisatest";
$allowed = array(0, 1);
if(in_array($string, $allowed, true)){
    echo "In array";
} else {
    echo "Not in array";
}
```