# Why PHP condition getting true even if i am checking equal to

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $test = "-3,-13";
    if ($test == -3) {
        echo "yay";
    } else {
        echo "nay";
    }

?>
```

why it always runs through if condition and not going in else condition? I am new to php so do not know what's going on here.

Comment: You are comparing a string value to a number, so the string needs to be converted into a number - and the result of that simply is `-3`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing String to Integer gives strange results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672040/comparing-string-to-integer-gives-strange-results)

Comment: `==` conversion , `===` no conversion...

Answer (score 1):

The string is converted into an integer `"-3, 46, blala"` -> `-3` , then the condition is evaluated.

Use the `===` operator to avoid conversion.

Most of the time, you do not want to let php do the conversion in your place (security problem). Rather, the request is refused.

Answer (score 0):

As PHP documentation says

```
Example     Name    Result
$a == $b    Equal   TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type juggling.
$a === $b   Identical   TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.
```

When we compare a number with a string, the string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.

```
var_dump(0 == "a"); // 0 == 0 -> true
var_dump("1" == "01"); // 1 == 1 -> true
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php