# PHP in_array function give annoying result

Tags: php, arrays, php-7

PHP 7

```
in_array('one', [0 => 0]) //true
in_array('one', [0]) //true
in_array('one', array_keys([0 => 0])); //true
```

Expected result is FALSE, because obviously there are no string values in given array, also there are no 'true' values (string can be evaluated to true and match)

If we assume any type comparsion 0 integer is always compared to false in PHP, and String compared to true, so why this works anyway?

I know, strict mode exists and works fine, but anyway absolute annoying why this happend. Any explanation?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: It should be FASLE, there are no values in array matching string 'one'

Comment: Please add that to your question. We need to know what's going on to help you!

Comment: I did this,please check

Comment: read [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) on type comparisons, and as you say, always use strict so you won't shoot yourself in the foot... - an [answer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#49327) from 15 years ago explains it in short.

Comment: Okay 0 integer is always compared to false in PHP, and String compared to true, so why this works ?

Comment: have a look at [this](https://3v4l.org/jdZm0) it also shows there's a change for PHP8.0.0. beta1-beta3 (string "one" DOES NOT equal 0 anymore)

Comment: But Strings ("one") always been casted to (1 or true) that means 0 != "one" but it gives true if we use in_array

Comment: @user1713785 no, `'one'` is `true` in a **boolean** context. In an integer context (e.g. comparing it to `0`), the string is converted to an integer; and since it doesn't begin with any digits, it evaluates to `0`. See for example https://3v4l.org/XpEUp, `'1one' == 1` but `'one' == 0`

Comment: @jibsteroos interesting, I had not noticed that in the updates.

Comment: @Nick, yeah, same here, it just struck me when I ran it on 3v4l

Comment: @user1713785 absolutely correct. My opinion was it should be casted to boolean. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is here:

[Comparing String to Integer gives strange results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672040/comparing-string-to-integer-gives-strange-results)

Same situation when `"one" == 0` as in your examples.

TL:DR - on string-to-integer comparison the string will be converted to integer, not the integer to string, so "one" will be converted to `0`

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking it should be casted to boolean. Now I see the integer is more close in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> in_array works when u use it like this

```
in_array('one', [0,1])
```

Comment: Nope, in_array('one', [0,1]) //true, when should false

Answer (score 0):

`in_array` function  expect array as indexed array i.e `[0,1,"two"]` not **associative array** (Key value pair).
You can use `array_values` to ignore the key of specific, it returns only values.

```
in_array('one', array_values([0 => 0])) // true //tested
```

Comment: I faced this problem starting from array_keys, in your example also result is TRUE when it should be FALSE. Look at my fist post, edited

Comment: @user1713785 `in_array('one', array_values([0 => 0]),TRUE)` pass 3rd parameter `TRUE` for **type specefic**. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, i know about strict mode, thi is intresting behavior when in default mode